# O usuário excluiu a pergunta pouco antes de finalizar a resposta

Tags: debate

O que devo fazer quando um usuário apaga sua pergunta logo antes de eu publicar uma resposta?

O AP havia postado essa pergunta.

<kbd>[image: pergunta apagada]</kbd>

Porém eu já estava acabando de escrever uma resposta.

> Primeiramente eu não entendi alguns campos de sua tabela, já que é
>   possível fazer o que você quer sem eles, acredito que alguns sejam até
>   redundantes.
>
> Você pode fazer uma estrutura N pra N da seguinte forma.
>
> ```
> [comentarios] N - <votos_comentarios>  N - [usuarios]
> ```
>
> Vou demonstrar usando SQL mas isso é independente da implementação,
>   você pode fazer em qualquer linguagem, é só pra entender a lógica.
>
> **Tabela**: comentarios
>
> ```
> cod_comentario INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
> cod_usuario INT NOT NULL,
> comentario varchar(600),
> ativo BIT DEFAULT 1
> ```
>
> Observações: Acredito que você queira ter a possibilidade de "apagar"
>   um comentário porém manter ele na base de dados, portanto precisa
>   definir se ele esta ativo ou não, use `0` para `false` ou `1` para
>   `true` no campo `ativo`.
>
> **Tabela:** votos_comentarios
>
> ```
> cod_comentario INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
> cod_usuario INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
> voto INT
> PRIMARY KEY (cod_comentario, cod_usuario)
> FOREIGN KEY(cod_comentario) REFERENCES comentarios(cod_comentario),
> FOREIGN KEY(cod_usuario) REFERENCES usuarios(cod_usuario),
> ```
>
> Observações: O campo `voto` deve receber 1 como voto positivo, e -1
>   como voto negativo. Você pode definir outro padrão para seu projeto,
>   desde que seja consistente e não altere depois de já haver registros
>   em tabela.
>
> Sendo `cod_usuario` e `cod_comentario` uma chave primária composta na
>   tabela `votos_comentario`, ela não vai pode se repetir duas vezes
>   quando o usuário 1 votar na pergunta 1, porém poderá aceitar quando o
>   usuário 1 votar no comentário 2 (porém não duas vezes também, isso vai
>   proteger o seu banco de quem esteja programando).
>
> Quando algum usuário alterar o seu voto, deverá ser executado um
>   update. Apenas tome cuidado para não excluir literalmente comentários
>   que possuam ligações na tabela `votos_comentarios`.
>
> Para contar os votos agora fica fácil e você não terá necessidade de
>   armazenar um valor redundante dentro do seu banco.

**Devo desconsiderar a resposta e jogar fora ou nesse caso deve ser tomado outro procedimento**?

Comment: A propósito, tem um leve erro de português na tradução: "Esta pergunta foi **removido**".

Comment: Relacionadas: [O que fazer quando um usuário remove a pergunta sem aviso?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2425/91) e [Reversão de Exclusão](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1903/91)

Comment: @RenanCavalieri Acho que consegui acertar a tradução, mas só tem como ter certeza daqui a algumas horas, quando o site fizer um build

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Você não *deve* fazer nada, mas *pode* fazer alguma coisa.

Primeiro, eu sei que é ruim perder o trabalho de uma resposta. Isso já aconteceu comigo duas ou três vezes.

Mas o que fazer? Algumas opções:

- **Deixar pra lá**. Em geral é bom respeitar a decisão do usuário que excluiu a pergunta e descartar seu trabalho ou guardar para uso futuro.
- **Trazer para o meta**. Aqui podemos discutir se o conteúdo é algo valioso para a comunidade e então decidir o que fazer. Em alguns poucos casos há a possibilidade de ressuscitar a pergunta, desde é claro, que ela não tenha conteúdo sensível ou que o usuário tenha explicitamente solicitado a sua remoção.
- **Faça a pergunta você mesmo**. Após uma discussão no meta ou mesmo por sua própria convicção, chegou-se à conclusão que seria um ganho para o site e benefício para os visitantes ter a resposta lá. Então você pode simplesmente criar uma nova pergunta e respondê-la com o conteúdo que havia criado. Nesse caso, evite simplesmente copiar a pergunta anterior, é melhor refazê-la para deixá-la melhor e evitar conflitos com outros usuários.

Em todo caso, sugiro apenas levar o assunto adiante se você tem confiança de ter uma resposta muito boa, isto é, algo de valor que seja independente do problema que o autor da pergunta original tinha.